# How can I conditionally include a syntax file from another syntax file?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have a custom syntax plugin for a file format that can contain embedded HLSL or GLSL code. At the moment, I've manually included a bunch of `syntax keyword` and `syntax match` commands in my syntax file to cover the basics of HLSL or GLSL source. I'd *prefer* to simply reference an existing HLSL syntax plugin via `syntax include`, but there is no built-in HLSL or GLSL syntax support in vim, so I cannot expect that a `syntax include` will succeed.

I'd like to *attempt* to execute `syntax include`, and if it fails (or would fail), fall back to my half-hearted custom version. How can I accomplish this?

I've looked at `try`/`endtry`, but they didn't seem to allow me to avoid an error if the desired syntax file wasn't present, and in any case only work on vim 7.0 or greater, and *if possible* I'd like to use a version-agnostic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`:help :runtime`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3aruntime)

> When `'verbose'` is one or higher, there is a message when no file could be found.

This uses `:echomsg` to print the error, which you can capture like:

```
redir => error
    verbose silent runtime syntax/cx.vim
redir END
```

---

I've found that using `:redir` in startup scripts is sometimes problematic though, sometimes Vim mixes up which redir belongs to which variable, so alternatively you can just use a loop to scan each entry in the `runtimepath`:

```
let found = 0
for path in split(&runtimepath, ',')
    if file_readable(path . '/fname.vim')
        execute 'source ' . path . '/fname.vim'
        let found = 1
        break
    endif
endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `try`/`endtry` did not seem to work for me after a cursory attempt, I resorted to relying on the behavior of `syntax include` which states that a relative path is searched for in the runtime path, and put this in my syntax file:

```
let b:has_hlsl_support = 0
for directory in split(&runtimepath, ",")
  if filereadable(simplify(directory . "/syntax/hlsl.vim"))
    let b:has_hlsl_support = 1
    break
  endif
endfor
```

Then I can check `b:has_hlsl_support` and branch accordingly. This works, but I find myself wondering if there's a superior method.